# JSON Data into data sets

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, loops, object

```
{
    "count": '2',
    "data": [{
        "value": "58",
        "color": "red"
    }, {
        "value": "45",
        "color": "blue"
    }, {
        "value": "32",
        "color": "yellow"
    }, {
        "value": "25",
        "color": "orange"
    }]
}
```

I would like this data into 2 data sets. something like below

```
"dataone": [{
    "value": "58",
    "color": "red"
}, {
    "value": "45",
    " color": "blue"
}];
"dataatwo": [{
    "value": "32",
    "color": "yellow"
}, {
    "value": "25",
    "color": "orange"
}];
```

How do I iterate above JSON data to generate the data sets using Javascript.

Comment: Folks here usually don't write code from scratch. If you have tried something yourself, please add the code to your question so people can see it and try to help you with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var i, res = {}, _data, names = ['dataone', 'datatwo'];

for (i = 0; i < +json.count; i++) {
  _data = json.data.splice(0, +json.count);

  if (_data && _data.length) {
    res[names[i]] = _data;
  }
}
```

Demo: [http://jsbin.com/mitagi/2/](http://jsbin.com/mitagi/2/edit?js,console)

Answer (score 0):

```
var a={
    "count": '2',
    "data": [{
        "value": "58",
        "color": "red"
    }, {
        "value": "45",
        "color": "blue"
    }, {
        "value": "32",
        "color": "yellow"
    }, {
        "value": "25",
        "color": "orange"
    }]
}

var d1= { dataone: a.data.slice(0,a.count) };
var d2= { datatwo: a.data.slice(count) };
console.log(d1);
console.log(d2);
```

General case

```
a.data.forEach(function(e,i){ 
   if(i%a.count==0) 
      console.log(a.data[i],a.data[i+1]);
   }
)
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

http://jsfiddle.net/uoh63kx4/3/

```
var json = {
    "count": '2',
    "data": [{
        "value": "58",
        "color": "red"
    }, {
        "value": "45",
        "color": "blue"
    }, {
        "value": "32",
        "color": "yellow"
    }, {
        "value": "25",
        "color": "orange"
    }]
};
var dataone=[];
var dataatwo=[];

    for(var i=0;i<json.count;i++)
    {
        dataone.push(json.data[i])
    }

    for(var i=json.count;i<json.data.length;i++)
    {
        dataatwo.push(json.data[i])
    }
    console.log(dataone);
    console.log(dataatwo);
```